# Execute handler function after tap on UIAlertAction of UIAlertController *SpriteKit*

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, uialertcontroller

I am trying to get a UIAlterController to display (as soon as the scene is set up) with the following buttons:

1. Accept - won't do anything, just close the UIAlertController
2. Leave to Menu - should transition to the MenuScene

My code looks as follows (I put the alert controller inside an action so it first displays the scene and after 0.5 seconds it should start displaying the alert):

```
//make action
var actionBlock = SKAction.runBlock({
  //alert controller
  var alert = UIAlertController(title: "Welcome", message: "Are you sure you want to proceed?", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
  //action with no handler
  var acceptAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Yes", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, handler: nil)
  //action thats supposed to transition to MenuScene (AFTER BEING TAPPED!!)
  var leaveAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Back to Menu", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Destructive, handler: {_ in self.backToMenu()})
  //add action to the alert controller
  alert.addAction(acceptAction)
  alert.addAction(leaveAction)
  //add alert controller to view
  self.view?.window?.rootViewController?.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
//wait for 0.5s action
var wait = SKAction.waitForDuration(0.5)
//run the action
self.runAction(SKAction.sequence([wait, actionBlock]))
```

and I placed it right into the DidMoveToView function. When I run the code, it immediately transitions back to the MenuScene without even waiting for the user to tap either one of the actions, and then the alert is still on the screen (but on the MenuScene). 
I am really confused and I've been on this for several hours but I just can't figure out what my mistake is, and how to make it work..
Anybody help please? Any code that works would be really appreciated!!!